# In GoLand, how do you find the list of functions associated with a struct or a type

Tags: go, goland

I am using GoLand IDE for Golang development. Just wondering if there is a way to find the list of functions implemented for a given struct or a type?

Comment: Do you want a list of methods defined on a type? Or you want a list of functions that accept or return or otherwise reference the type?

Answer (score 1):

Just found out, it is CTRL+Q (cursor on the type) to get the list of functions for a given type or struct.